# How to group and label geom_col in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am trying to reproduce graph from GraphPad using R and ggplot2. 
I have values for few samples in few conditions:

```
df <- data.frame(Sample = c("blank", "blank", "blank", "A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B", "B", "C","C","C","C","C","C"), 
                 Condition = c("control", "control", "control", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C2","C1", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C2","C1", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C2"),
                 Value = c(0.719, 1.25, 0.687, 8.19, 4.68, 3.53, 14.1, 7.11, 8.8, 6.48, 7.05, 4.82, 6.32, 4.97, 6.97, 5.5, 7.22, 6.89, 8.89, 6.83, 8.73))

df$Sample <- factor(df$Sample, levels = c("blank", "A", "B", "C")) 
df$Condition <- factor(df$Condition, levels = c("control", "C1", "C2"))
```

I am struggling to organize and plot them as groupped (by condition) and labeled (by sample), like that:

[image: GraphPad image]

I tried using `fill` and `position="dodge"` but it is totally not what I want:

```
df %>%
  ggplot + 
  aes(x = Sample, y = Value, fill = Condition) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image: ggplot]

Note, that I would also like to exclude blank from the legend.

I was trying with creating, plotting and labeling another column, such as:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Sample.Condition = paste(Sample, Condition, sep = "."))
```

..but it is getting (too?) complicated. For sake of learning I am looking for simple and neat solutions on how to do that. 
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the creating a labeling another column is the way to make ggplot do this. What you want is complicated, and not what ggplot wants to do. ggplot likes to map a column to the x-axis, and label each unique value from that column. You don't have any column that corresponds to the 7 unique values you want on the x-axis, so you will need to create one. Dodging works for separating out groups *within a single x-axis break*, which are usually visually separated by color or shape, because they don't get their own labels. You want labels for each, so dodging won't work.

Comment: The only other option I see is to facet by condition, which will get the grouping/ordering right, but not really be on the same plot. With a few `theme` tweaks you could make them look pretty similar, but this will be a lot more work than creating one new column.

Comment: Looks like extra column is still the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you succeed to get your plot, I found a way to do it if you are interested by:

First, I calculate `mean` and `sd` of `Values` for your dataset (which is what is represented on your Graphpad) and as suggested by @Gregor, I create a new column which is the concatenation of `Sample` and `Condition`

```r
library(dplyr)
df2 = df%>%
  group_by(Sample,Condition) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Value), Sd = sd(Value)) %>%
  mutate(New_Var = paste0(Sample,Condition))
```

Then, we can plot the data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2, aes(x = New_Var, y = Mean, fill = Condition)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black",position = position_dodge(), width = 0.7) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean - Sd, ymax = Mean + Sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black","grey","red"),
                    labels = c("Control","Condition 1", "Condition 2")) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("blankcontrol","AC1","BC1","CC1","AC2","BC2","CC2") , labels = c("Blank","A","B","C","A","B","C")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold",angle = 45),
        legend.title = element_blank()) +
  xlab("") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,15), breaks = c(0,5,10,15))
```

And the plot looks pretty similar to the one you get from GraphPad. I agree it's not an easy task to do but if you really want this plot, you can get it.
[image]

**EDIT - ADDING INDIVIDUAL VALUES ON THE GRAPH**

```r
library(dplyr)
dfX= df %>%
  mutate(New_Var2 = paste0(Sample,Condition))
```

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2, aes(x = New_Var, y = Mean, fill = Condition)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black",position = position_dodge(), width = 0.7) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean - Sd, ymax = Mean + Sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black","grey","red"),
                    labels = c("Control","Condition 1", "Condition 2")) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("blankcontrol","AC1","BC1","CC1","AC2","BC2","CC2") , labels = c("Blank","A","B","C","A","B","C")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold",angle = 45),
        legend.title = element_blank()) +
  xlab("") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,15), breaks = c(0,5,10,15))+
  geom_jitter(data = dfX, aes(x = New_Var2, y = Value), position=position_jitter(0.3), show.legend = F)
```

And you get the following graph:
[image]

However, with only three points per conditions, I will rather represent mean as a single point with sd as an error bar. Something like that.

```r
ggplot(df2, aes(x = New_Var, y = Mean, group = Condition)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = Condition, color= Condition), stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(), size = 2) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean - Sd, ymax = Mean + Sd, color = Condition), width = .2, position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(15, 16, 17))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black","darkgrey","darkred"), labels = c("Control","Condition 1", "Condition 2")) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("blankcontrol","AC1","BC1","CC1","AC2","BC2","CC2") , labels = c("Blank","A","B","C","A","B","C")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold",angle = 45),
        legend.title = element_blank()) +
  xlab("") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,15), breaks = c(0,5,10,15))+
  geom_jitter(data = dfX, aes(x = New_Var2, y = Value, shape = Condition), 
              position=position_jitter(0.3), color = adjustcolor("black",alpha.f = 0.6), 
              show.legend = F, size = 2)
```

And the resulting graph:
[image]

But it is just my personal opinion, it's up to you ;)

Comment: that is indeed very neat solution. How about when I want to add individual points on top of that (geom_dotplot)?

Comment: Glad you're appreciated it. You mean one points for each barchart ?

Comment: For adding points, you can add a new column by doing `df2 = data.frame(df2,points = c(5,11,15,9.5,15,10,12))` and then add at the end of the ggplot `geom_point(aes(x=New_Var, y = points))`. That should add one point on top of each barchart. Is it waht you're looking for ?

Comment: Not really. I mean ALL data points used to calculate values (in this case mean and sd) for each column. It will be like geom_dotplot mapped to x = New_Var and y = Values on the original df with something like inner_join to create such New_Var column. Publishers ask about that, that is why its so important.

Comment: Ok, I get it, I will edit my answer for adding values in the graph.

Comment: Wow, that is really great solution. I really appreciate your effort in dealing with that question, hope others will also benefit. That really makes ggplot a great tool for publication-ready graphs. I am just wondering: how about custom order for conditions? In this example it's easy sortable ABC but my real case contains gene names that has to be ordered manually (eg B A C). How to deal with  it? And yes, there are only 3  data points for each condition but its just example dataset, real one have more of them :)

Comment: You're welcome ;) For ordering conditions, you have to play with the `scale_x_discrete` and sets `limits` in the right order. If you want "BAC", you can enter `scale_x_discrete(limits = c("blankcontrol","BC1","AC1","CC1","BC2","AC2","CC2") , labels = c("Blank","B","A","C","B","A","C"))`. Good luck for your publication.

Answer (score 2):

The neatest solution is probably the introduction of facets.

```
df %>%
  ggplot + 
  aes(x = Sample, y = Value, fill = Condition) + 
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~Condition)
```

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of facets, I was just hoping for some more "dedicated" solution. Thanks :)